# Implementation problem of storing and reusing objects with the same data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Imagine we have `UserInfo`. This class must contain info about objects called `Badge`. `UserInfo` can contain multiple `Badge`s or not contain it at all. `Badge` contains some info that common to all instances with same ID.

```
public class UserInfo
{  
    HashSet<Badge> Badges { get; set; }  
    //UserInfo can't have two badges with the same ID
}

public class Badge
{
    public int BadgeId;
    //Below we have info that common to all badges with same ID
    public string Name;
    public string ImagePath;
    ...
}
```

Implementation above is not final, just an example from my head.
**Questions:**

1. If I have thousands of `UserInfo` objects, I would not want memory to be littered with unique `Badge` instances, because most of them still have the same information (within the same ID, of course). Is it real to solve that problem elegantly.
2. How do I store relationships in EF Core DB. I have not encountered a similar problem before. It seems to me that creating a unique entry for each `UserInfo` - `Badge` bundle is not an option. Is it so?

The problem is that there are many such relationships in the application. In my application there are not only `Badge` but also other similar classes.
Information about existing `Badge` never changes. Also I need to retreive `Badge`'s data fast. What's the better way to implement it

Comment: So, to get your question right:
Is what you ask, to "index" your Badges inside a database, using the mapping of Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes. How can I map it well, without creating millions of raws in database. And how can I optimize memory using without creating many instances of `Badge` for every `UserInfo` object.
If I need to split the questions on 2 posts tell me please.

Comment: That's strange, why a User needs to have more than one Badge?

Comment: @Steve imagine it like boy scout badge. Boy scout can have multiple merit badges or not to have it at all. I did not invent this. My application works with an external source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### Dislamer
>
> The following information is what I currently use and have worked for me. That said, I'm not an EFCore expert, so, If there is a more appropriate way of doing this, I'm open to learn.
>
> Additionally, I assume you have a basic understanding of how EFCore6 works
> so, i'm not getting into detail about how to setup your application, how to inject/use your DbContext, Database Migrations, etc.

### Basic Scheme

According you the information you provided, your desired Objects-Relations diagram should look kinda like following

[image: Objects-Relations diagram]

That means your basic objects should look like following:

```cs
public class UserInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Badge> Badges { get; set; }
}

public class Badge
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    // this is mandatory. It won't be loaded
    // unless specifically demanded.
    // so, no worries about memory usage!
    private List<UserInfo> _users;
}
```

### Code

Now, on your `DbContext` class you need to define two DbSets that represent your two tables, `Badges` and `UserInfo`.

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext{
    public DbSet<UserInfo> UserInfo {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Badge> Badges {get; set;}

    // [...]
}
```

Last coding step is to define the relations of your databese, by overwritting `OnModelCreating` method as follows:

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext{
    public DbSet<UserInfo> UserInfo {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Badge> Badges {get; set;}

    // [...]
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // We define our User Info Entity
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserInfo>(u =>
        {
            // With ID property as the key
            u.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            // And a Many-to-Many relation with the
            // to-be-defined Badges table.
            // We don't want access to users from
            // a badge, that's why our property
            // is private and we define it
            // by it's navigation name (_users)
            u.HasMany(x => x.Badges).WithMany("_users");
        });

        // We define our Badges Entity
        modelBuilder.Entity<Badge>(b =>
        {
            // With ID property as the key
            b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            // Our relation is defined
            // above. No need to redefine it.
        });
    }
}
```

### Migrations

Now you're ready to migrate your database using your favourite method
(using Package-Manager Console of Visual Studio or using dotnet entity framework cli tool with `dotnet-ef migrations add "MigrationNameHere"` and `dotnet-ef database update`).

### Important notes

In order to access the linked badges of a user, you have to specifically ask for it, when querying your DbContext. Let's say you want the badges of user with Id `5`:

```
MyDbContext ctx = your_db_context;

var userOfInterest = ctx
   .UserInfo
   .Include(x => x.Badges)  // THIS line!
   .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == 5)l

if (userOfInterest is not null){
   // Do stuff with userOfInterest.Badges
}
```