# How to create many-to-many relationship with custom ApplicationUser class MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to link two tables (AspNetUsers which uses custom ApplicationUser class, and a custom Projects class). I want the users to have multiple projects, and vice versa. I have added the following code into both of my models; however, when doing migrations and updating the database, no linking table is created.

Here is my ApplicationUser class:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using IssueTracker.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace IssueTracker.Areas.Identity.Data
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            this.Projects = new HashSet<ProjectModel>();
        }

        public String? FirstName { get; set; }

        public String? LastName { get; set; }

        public String? Role { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProjectModel> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is my Project model class:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using IssueTracker.Areas.Identity.Data;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace IssueTracker.Models
{
    public class ProjectModel
    {
        public ProjectModel()
        {
            this.Users = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public string? Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and here is my DbContext:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using IssueTracker.Models;

namespace IssueTracker.Areas.Identity.Data;

public class IssueTrackerIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<ProjectModel> Projects { get; set; }

    public IssueTrackerIdentityDbContext()
    {

    }

    public IssueTrackerIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<IssueTrackerIdentityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserEntityConfiguration());
    }


}

public class ApplicationUserEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(u => u.FirstName).HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(u => u.LastName).HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}
```

After running a migration with the code above, I am given this migration which does not create a table to link the two.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace IssueTracker.Migrations
{
    public partial class UserProjectTable : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
                name: "ID",
                table: "Projects",
                newName: "Id");

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "ApplicationUserId",
                table: "Projects",
                type: "TEXT",
                nullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Projects_ApplicationUserId",
                table: "Projects",
                column: "ApplicationUserId");

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Projects_AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId",
                table: "Projects",
                column: "ApplicationUserId",
                principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                principalColumn: "Id");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Projects_AspNetUsers_ApplicationUserId",
                table: "Projects");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_Projects_ApplicationUserId",
                table: "Projects");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "ApplicationUserId",
                table: "Projects");

            migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
                name: "Id",
                table: "Projects",
                newName: "ID");
        }
    }
}
```

How should I update my code so that I can properly create a many-to-many relationship between ApplicationUser and Projects. Also, once this relationship is created, how can I properly access and modify the relationship. Do I need to update all 3 classes whenever a user is added to a project (or vice versa), or do I solely need to update the linking table. Thank you so much! I am new to MVC so forgive me if this is very rudimentary.

Comment: About creating a many-to-many relationship on EFCore, you can check my recent answer at [Implementation problem of storing and reusing objects with the same data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73212478/implementation-problem-of-storing-and-reusing-objects-with-the-same-data/).

Comment: Yes, but since I am using the AspNetUsers table, which is built in to Identity, do I need to still create a DbSet of ApplicationUsers in the DbContext?

Comment: No, there is one already defined, called `Users`. That means you don't need to call `modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(...)` either, because the user entity is already defined.
That said, i'd suggest defining the one-to-many relationship from within the second entity's definition (aka the `badge` entity of my example, not the `user info`) to avoid possible configuration overwrites.

Comment: Try regenerating the migration. Either `ProjectModel.Users` collection was not there, or for some unknown reason EF Core does not see it or ignores it, or there are some navigation properties not shown here. The regenerate test is to exclude the case #1. From the shown migration, looks like EF Core considers one-to-many relationship.

Comment: So should the relationship be defined like this `modelBuilder.Entity<Badge>(b =>
        {
            b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            b.HasMany(x => x._users).WithMany("Badges");
        });`

Comment: If your goal is to access all of user badges *FROM THE USER* (So, you cannot easily go "show me the users that have this badge") as the one i'm describing, it should be 
`modelBuilder.Entity<Badge>(b =>{b.HasKey(x => x.Id);  b.HasMany<ApplicationUser>("_users").WithMany(u => u.Badges); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this too:

```
public class ApplicationUserEntityConfiguration : 
IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
{
    builder.Property(u => u.FirstName).HasMaxLength(255);
    builder.Property(u => u.LastName).HasMaxLength(255);


    builder.HasMany(x => x.Projects).WithMany(x => x.Users);
}
}
```